# How can i install a composer package in nwidart laravel-modules

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

Also i using: https://github.com/nWidart/laravel-modules this.

and i created a module with php artisan module:make MollieModule

Now i will install this package https://github.com/mollie/mollie-api-php with composer require mollie/mollie-api-php:^2.0 in the MollieModule folder. But when i installing it in there comes this error: on picture 2 when i update the module with php artisan module:update MollieModule

[image]

why comes:
[image]

then... its in the module how can make that?